# Error with Using Mixins in Minecraft Fabric Modding

Tags: java, mixins, minecraft-fabric

I tried to redirecte the Method tickMovement() in the SnowGolemEntity class to remove the passage where snow golems get damage from beeing in Hot biomes. I tried to start Minecraft but it failed.

I did the setup of my fabric modding environment exactly like on the fabric website (https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:setup) described.

Thanks for the help in advance.

The Java Code:

```
@Mixin(SnowGolemEntity.class)
abstract class ExampleMixin  {

    @Redirect(
            method = "tickMovement",
            at = @At(
                    value = "INVOKE",
                    target = "Lnet/minecraft/entity/passive/SnowGolemEntity;tickMovement()V"
            )
    )
    private void tickMovement() {

    }
}
```

Heres the stacktrace:

```
[11:32:39] [main/ERROR] (FabricLoader) Minecraft has crashed!
 net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FormattedException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:462) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74) [fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverDebugConfig.<clinit>(CarverDebugConfig.java:14) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.method_33968(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.serialization.codecs.RecordCodecBuilder.mapCodec(RecordCodecBuilder.java:76) ~[datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.<clinit>(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.Carver.<clinit>(Carver.java:55) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.ConfiguredCarvers.<clinit>(ConfiguredCarvers.java:30) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30572(BuiltinRegistries.java:57) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30566(BuiltinRegistries.java:107) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.<clinit>(BuiltinRegistries.java:106) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:518) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:51) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:147) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:460) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Mixin transformation of net.minecraft.entity.passive.SnowGolemEntity failed
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.getPostMixinClassByteArray(KnotClassDelegate.java:418) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.tryLoadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:322) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:218) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:145) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.block.Blocks.<clinit>(Blocks.java:470) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverDebugConfig.<clinit>(CarverDebugConfig.java:14) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.method_33968(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.serialization.codecs.RecordCodecBuilder.mapCodec(RecordCodecBuilder.java:76) ~[datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.<clinit>(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.Carver.<clinit>(Carver.java:55) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.ConfiguredCarvers.<clinit>(ConfiguredCarvers.java:30) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30572(BuiltinRegistries.java:57) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30566(BuiltinRegistries.java:107) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.<clinit>(BuiltinRegistries.java:106) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:518) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:51) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:147) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:460) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.throwables.MixinTransformerError: An unexpected critical error was encountered
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:392) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClass(MixinTransformer.java:234) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClassBytes(MixinTransformer.java:202) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.getPostMixinClassByteArray(KnotClassDelegate.java:413) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.tryLoadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:322) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:218) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:145) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.block.Blocks.<clinit>(Blocks.java:470) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverDebugConfig.<clinit>(CarverDebugConfig.java:14) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.method_33968(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.serialization.codecs.RecordCodecBuilder.mapCodec(RecordCodecBuilder.java:76) ~[datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.<clinit>(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.Carver.<clinit>(Carver.java:55) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.ConfiguredCarvers.<clinit>(ConfiguredCarvers.java:30) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30572(BuiltinRegistries.java:57) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30566(BuiltinRegistries.java:107) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.<clinit>(BuiltinRegistries.java:106) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:518) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:51) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:147) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:460) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.injection.throwables.InjectionError: Critical injection failure: Redirector tickMovement()V in modid.mixins.json:ExampleMixin from mod modid failed injection check, (0/1) succeeded. Scanned 1 target(s). No refMap loaded.
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.injection.struct.InjectionInfo.postInject(InjectionInfo.java:468) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTargetContext.applyInjections(MixinTargetContext.java:1385) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinApplicatorStandard.applyInjections(MixinApplicatorStandard.java:1052) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinApplicatorStandard.applyMixin(MixinApplicatorStandard.java:400) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinApplicatorStandard.apply(MixinApplicatorStandard.java:325) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.apply(TargetClassContext.java:421) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.applyMixins(TargetClassContext.java:403) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:363) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClass(MixinTransformer.java:234) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClassBytes(MixinTransformer.java:202) ~[sponge-mixin-0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5.jar:0.11.4+mixin.0.8.5]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.getPostMixinClassByteArray(KnotClassDelegate.java:413) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.tryLoadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:322) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:218) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:145) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.block.Blocks.<clinit>(Blocks.java:470) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverDebugConfig.<clinit>(CarverDebugConfig.java:14) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.method_33968(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.serialization.codecs.RecordCodecBuilder.mapCodec(RecordCodecBuilder.java:76) ~[datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.CarverConfig.<clinit>(CarverConfig.java:18) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.Carver.<clinit>(Carver.java:55) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.carver.ConfiguredCarvers.<clinit>(ConfiguredCarvers.java:30) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30572(BuiltinRegistries.java:57) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.method_30566(BuiltinRegistries.java:107) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.BuiltinRegistries.<clinit>(BuiltinRegistries.java:106) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:518) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:51) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:147) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:460) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.6.jar:?]
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error says it didn't find the place where you wanted it to insert the mixin. Is there a call to tickMovement() inside of tickMovement() ? That's where you're telling it to insert the mixin.

Comment: In the tickMovement() Method is another tickMovement() call to a superclass. Is there any way of specifiying wich of those methods i want to redirect?

Comment: yes, do you see the two places where you wrote SnowGolemEntity in your mixin?

Comment: yes, once at the top with the annotation and the other one in the targe = " ... " but what does this have to do with the problem

Comment: The @Mixin is which class gets edited by the mixin. The target= is the instruction where the edit happens. You're saying the edit happens inside SnowGolemEntity.tickMovement where there's a call to SnowGolemEntity.tickMovement, but you say it is actually calling tickMovement of the superclass and not the one of SnowGolemEntity

Comment: How do I specify that i want to redirect the tickMovement() Method in the snowgolementity.class and not the upper class one

Comment: If you want to delete an entire method and replace it with your own code, then you are looking for @ Overwrite rather than @ Redirect. Overwrite is discouraged because only one mod can overwrite the same method - if two mods overwrite the same method they won't load. Redirect can replace a single method *call*

Comment: kk if I shouldnt use overwrite though how can i achieve to remove a certain part of the code from the tickMovement() Method? Because my goal is to make snow golems immune to heat damage and I thought the easiest way is to remove the code where minecraft is checking if the snow golem is in a hot biome

Comment: Maybe you can redirect where it gets the biome so it always returns a cold biome. It seems like right now you don't actually know what you are trying to do. The point of a mixin is to change some of the code. Do you know which code you want to change, specifically?

Comment: I know what im trying to do lol I want to delete these 3 lines from the SnowGolemEntity.class so that Snowgolems dont recieve heat damage:

Comment: Biome biome = this.world.getBiome(blockPos);
            if (biome.isHot(blockPos)) {
                this.damage(DamageSource.ON_FIRE, 1.0F);
            }

Comment: then your easiest thing to do is Redirect either the isHot call so it always returns false, or the damage call so doesn't do anything. method="tickMovement" says which method in SnowGolemEntity is supposed to be modified, and the "at" clause says where in the method to modify - you want to target either the isHot or damage method (depending on which one you decide to change).

Comment: (Another possibility is to Inject the beginning of the damage method and cancel it if the entity is a snow golem and the damage is fire damage. This would make snow golems immune to fire damage, which wouldn't be exactly what you wanted, but if the other two ideas cause some compatibility problem with another mod, you might resort to this idea instead)